# Generate only models using Swagger-api / swagger-codegen

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

Generating the typescript-angular files from the downloaded jar [swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.34/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar)

Command

```
java -jar tools/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar generate \
  -i http://localhost:8080/swagger/fete-bird-api-gateway-0.0.yml \
  -l typescript-angular \
  -o libs/service/src/lib/swagger-specification \
  -Dmodels=true \
  -DmodelDocs=false -DmodelTests=false \
  -c tools/angular-swagger-option.json
```

The files are generated successfully, however, I am trying to generate only the models not the API, but the above command-generated API as well

[image]

Followed the instructions from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

```
# generate only models
java -Dmodels {opts}

# generate only apis
java -Dapis {opts}

# generate only supporting files
java -DsupportingFiles

# generate models and supporting files
java -Dmodels -DsupportingFiles
```

Not sure what should I pass {opts} so, that it generates only Models not api

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
java -jar tools/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar generate \
  -i http://localhost:8080/swagger/fete-bird-api-gateway-0.0.yml \
  -l typescript-angular \
  -o libs/service/src/lib/swagger-specification \
  -Dmodels
  -c tools/angular-swagger-option.json
```

or

```
java -Dmodels -jar tools/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar generate \
  -i http://localhost:8080/swagger/fete-bird-api-gateway-0.0.yml \
  -l typescript-angular \
  -o libs/service/src/lib/swagger-specification \
  -c tools/angular-swagger-option.json
```

It seems the combination of multiple -D parameters can be buggy

Answer (score 0):

For the CLI, you can comma-delimit -D params.

```
java -jar tools/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar generate \
  -i http://localhost:8080/swagger/fete-bird-api-gateway-0.0.yml \
  -l typescript-angular \
  -o libs/service/src/lib/swagger-specification \
  -Dmodels=true,modelDocs=false,modelTests=false \
  -c tools/angular-swagger-option.json
```

It is weird that the docs are wrong where. It's possible that they changed how they parsed options at one point. If you're interested in contributing to open source software, you could conceivably open a pull request to fix them!